# Some users cant see Mailbox Quota through Outlook

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2016

I am noticing a problem with some users (Not all) regarding mailbox storage and quotas.

In Outlook 2016, users can usually see how much of their mailbox storage is used up when they go to `File > Info`.  Like the image below;

---

[image]

---

Although, this is what some of my users see instead.

---

[image]

---

I was wondering if anyone had any insight as to why that is.

I will continue to look for a reason and post what I find.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post up a screenshot of one of the users who doesn't get the indicator?

Comment: I can in a moment, although it looks exactly like the screenshot I provided without the "Bar" and quota information below **Mailbox Cleanup**

Comment: @Kinnectus Added what the users see.  Let me know if you need anything else.  Thanks

Comment: https://justaucguy.wordpress.com/2012/05/25/outlook-2010-mailbox-usage-bar-graph/

Comment: @Kinnectus Thank you for finding this.  That is definitely an answer.  Although, I would never want mailboxes to be refused receiving emails.  Odd that it will not provide the indicator just cause of that.

Comment: The reason why you need both values is because the graph displays current space utilisation AND over utilisation (i.e. "100MB over 1GB"). It would be nice if it could work with one or both - it wouldn't be a difficult change, surely, Microsoft? Finally, did the link point to a solution? If it did let me know so i can write up an answer :)

Comment: @Kinnectus This was the answer I was looking for.  While it is not convenient to my environment, it was still the answer to the question.  Write up the answer and I will mark it.  Thanks again!